# insert an HTML element inside several components

Tags: html, angular, angular2-directives, viewchild

I am a beginner with angular and I am looking to insert this piece of HTML code in some templates of my components :

```
<ng-template #alertMessage>
        <p *ngIf="!displayProductInfo" id="alertMessage">Please enter a bar code to display a model.</p>
</ng-template>
```

Should I use the TemplateRef object with the @ViewChild() decorator or should I use directives ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Why not just make it a separate component with an @Input of `displayProductInfo` ?

Answer (score 1):

you should just use it by the component reference on the other components and if it requires input binding then do that or bind it to a service.  you can pass whatever you need to this way - a directive is overkill and ViewChild unless given a very specific Dom event or object is not going to do much for you.  The correct way is like below - but of course with your components name.  if you want to pass it in variables from each individual parent

```
<app-your-component [YOURINPUTRECEIVED]="yourlocalinputsent"></app-your-component>
```

in the imported component typescript

```
@Input() YOURINPUTRECEIVED ?: any;
```

or bind it via a service with **behavior subject** or **subject** using rxjs.

this way you can use the component at your leisure and import it into each template.

Comment: So I have to use templateref if I understood correctly? In my scenario I have nothing to pass in @Input(). Thank you

Comment: no you should just use the component and pass it an input binding of the data that you need.